# DSE Solr, numfound > 0 but docs returned are empty, field is set true for both index/store

Tags: solr, cassandra, bigdata, datastax

There are questions similar to this, but they didnt answer/resolve my problem so adding a new one.

I am using a Datastax 5 node cluster with 4 solr nodes.
I created a table in cassandra having single column and LZ4 compression with following script -

```sql
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytable (
  myfield text,
  PRIMARY KEY (myfield)
);
```

Then I added solrconfig.xml and schema.xml and created a core for my table.Below is snapshot from schema.xml

```xml
<types>
  <fieldType name="someField" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
      <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
</types>

<fields>
  <field name="myfield" type="someField" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
</fields>

<uniqueKey>myfield</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>myfield</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

I insert few records to my table using cassandra cqlsh.

```sql
INSERT INTO mykeyspace.mytable (myfield) VALUES ('testStr1');
INSERT INTO mykeyspace.mytable (myfield) VALUES ('testStr2');
```

From Solr UI if I check numdocs and maxdocs I see an immediate reflection of insertion on all 4 nodes.

In datastax logs also I see following

```
DEBUG [Index WorkPool work thread-3] 2015-03-19 04:29:41,646 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 612) Updating key testStr1 on index mykeyspace.mytable
DEBUG [Index WorkPool work thread-0] 2015-03-19 04:29:41,744 AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.java (line 612) Updating key testStr2 on index mykeyspace.mytable
```

Now when I query even for *:* through Solr I get numdocs > 0, but docslist is empty. In a separate environment same steps/config works like charm and I am able to index and query data perfectly.

I do get INFO logs like below on both environments -

```
Trying to load resource admin-extra.html for core mykeyspace.mytable by querying from local node with CL QUORUM
No resource admin-extra.html found for core mykeyspace.mytable by querying from local node.
Trying to load resource admin-extra.html for core mykeyspace.mytable by looking for legacy resources...
No resource admin-extra.html found for core mykeyspace.mytable on any live node.
Couldn't find resource: admin-extra.html, ignoring...
```

There is no other error/warning in the log.
What could be wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

**#UPDATE 1**
I altered the solrconfig to hard commit, but that also didnt work.
then i tried to add data via solrj and invoke hard commit which also failed with following exception -

```
ERROR [http-8983-exec-2] 2015-03-20 04:51:58,360 SolrDispatchFilter.java (line 696) Error request exception: Solr requires that request parameters sent using application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type can be read through the request input stream. Unfortunately, the stream was empty / not available. This may be caused by another servlet filter calling ServletRequest.getParameter*() before SolrDispatchFilter, please remove it.
```

Finally I changed the table schema to have an integer primary key and post that things worked correctly like magic.

I am still unclear what was the issue with prior schema!!

Comment: DSE 4.5 installation.

Comment: 5 node faulty cluster ---- cqlsh 4.1.1, Cassandra 2.0.11.83, DSE 4.6.0, CQL spec 3.1.1, Thrift protocol 19.39.0;

Comment: 2 node cluster on which myfield as primary key worked ---- cqlsh 4.1.1, Cassandra 2.0.10.71, DSE 4.5.2, CQL spec 3.1.1, Thrift protocol 19.39.0

Comment: Do you mean it worked for DSE 4.5.2, but not for 4.6.0?

Comment: Yes, 4.5.2 is installed on my local machine, while 4.6.0 is on rackspace cluster, It seems like an environment issue, I face other challenges as well with 4.6.0 environment which I am unable to reproduce in local environment.

Comment: I would suggest to run both your local and remote environments on the same DSE version. Also, please note your original schema used an analyzed text type for the unique key, which is usually a bad practice.

Comment: sure, thnx for sparing time.

Answer (score -1):

You can't index a Column family that have Just one column and that column is at the same time its primary key

It is Solr limitation